# Formatar data com javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, data

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação na qual eu obtenho as postagens de uma página no facebook e preciso formatar a data de criação do post que obtenho via json da seguinte forma:

```
2018-01-12T11:25:41+0000
```

Qual função devo usar para formatar essa data para o padrão brasileiro?
Ex: 12/01/2018.

Comment: Tente colocar parte do código para ajudar.

Comment: Não está duplicado. Acima eu explico que esse valor 2018-01-12T11:25:41+0000 eu recebo via JSon. E não pela new Date();

Comment: É uma possível duplicata Odair, essa pergunta tem respostas parecidas com as que tem aqui e o objetivo é quase idêntico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível passar o *locale* quando se usa a função `toLocaleDateString()`:

```js
let data = new Date();
console.log(data.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR'));
```

Comment: Na verdade eu não obtenho a data via Date(); Esse valor já é retornado pra mim via JSon e eu quero mudar o formato dele para o padrão 12/01/2018.

Comment: O objeto Date recebe parametros, pode passar essa string para ele como na resposta do Matheus @Odair

Comment: Sim, @Odair nós entendemos, mas para poder utiliza-lo para fazer conversões você precisa transformar ele de String (JSON) para Date(), passando como Parametro no `new Date(string para transformar)`

Answer (score 5):

Instancie a `string` como um novo `Date` e use a função `toLocaleDateString()`

```js
var data = new Date('2018-01-12T11:25:41+0000');
console.log(data.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR'));
```